# google-api-python-client bug with media downloading

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

Used `google-api-python-client==1.6.2`

```
fh = io.BytesIO()
request = self.drive_service.files().export_media(
    fileId='1fwshPVKCACXgNxJtmGN94X-9RRrukiDs9q4s-n0nGlM',
    mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
)
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request, chunksize=1024)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download ", status.progress(), downloader._progress, downloader._total_size, done
```

Output:

```
Download  0.0 973060 None False
Download  0.0 1946120 None False
Download  0.0 2919180 None False
Download  0.0 3892240 None False
Download  0.0 4865300 None False
Download  0.0 5838360 None False
Download  0.0 6811420 None False
Download  0.0 7784480 None False
Download  0.0 8757540 None False
...
```

File size of downloading file is 973060 bytes. So, the library ignores `chunksize` parameter and did not stop. Never stop.

So, anyone can tell me Are my requirements too high or Is the library so bad?

Comment: Strange. Have you tried downloading files with different sizes and see if the behavior is still the same?

Comment: I tried different chunk sizes and files. I got that `chunksize` is always ignored (a file is downloaded in a one request) and many other files downloaded without infinite looping. I think the main problem in type of this file. It's Google doc created by a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about following sample?

**Sample :**

```
request = self.drive_service.files().export_media(
    fileId='1fwshPVKCACXgNxJtmGN94X-9RRrukiDs9q4s-n0nGlM',
    mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
).execute()
with open('sample.docx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(request)
```

If this doesn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes. It works. Thank you. It is useful for me, because there is no such sample in Google documentation.

Comment: @Alexandr Lupandin No problem. Thank you for your concern, too.

Answer (score 0):

[The `google-api-python-client` library has a bug where downloads will never be considered done if the `Content-length` or `Content-range` header is missing.](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/15)

And since `drive.files.export` does not support chunked downloads it does not return a `Content-length` or `Content-range` header.

You can download the file by simply calling `execute` on the `HttpRequest` since `drive.files.export` will always export the entire file in one request.

If you still want to use `MediaIoBaseDownload` for a more general workaround you can check if `MediaDownloadProgress.total_size` is `None`.

```
fh = io.BytesIO()
request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType=mime_type)
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)

done = False
while not done:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    if status.total_size is None:
        # https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/15
        done = True
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation of the problem. But why in this case use `MediaIoBaseDownload`? I think the best solution is simply call `execute()` as s described above. For example, my code will be
`fh = io.BytesIO().write(service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType=mime_type).execute())`
or simply
`content = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType=mime_type).execute()`

Comment: @AlexandrLupandin updated my answer and gave a more general workaround solution.